# Python - How to capture Date from an excel file

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that I would like to extract a date from, as well as all the other data.

When I had to do the same task for HTML files, I would use BeautifulSoup, RegEx, and dateutil. I'd read the HTML as a string, capture the entire `Sent:` line with RegEx, then parse out the date from the `Sent:` line with `parser.parse()`.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        html = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        a = pattern.findall(str(soup))[0]
        print("a:", a)
        d = parser.parse(a, fuzzy=True)
        print("year:", d.year)
        print("month:", d.month)
        print("day:", d.day)
```

For this excel sheet, I read it in with `df = pd.read_csv(file_path)`, then try `d = parser.parse(df, fuzzy=True)` as before, but it fails with the error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'read'`

Is there a way around this? Or a simpler way to capture the date inside of a single cell, as seen below? Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: would you append some exaple of your excel file?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` for an excel file? How about `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: Lol I guess that makes more sense doesn't it? Forgive me for being a novice. My problem still exists though....my goal is ultimately to export the data in this excel sheet to my Oracle database, but I need to somehow "capture" the date that is in the string "Sustainable Harvest Sector Quota Listing Jun 11 2013" that is in the first cell of the spreadsheet. I'd upload a simple picture but imgur won't allow me to, idk if it's down or if my computer is being dumb

Comment: I added in a picture of the data. Reading it in with `pd.read_excel` works and saves the intermediate step of turning it into a CSV file, but is RegEx the smartest way to go about capturing just that date in the first cell?